# Toast message does not work if activity is started via AlarmManager

Tags: java, android, android-activity, alarmmanager, android-toast

I am in the process of testing my application on a real device.
The app should launch on its own at a specific time. I am using AlarmManager to launch it. The application starts at the defined time but toast message do not work.
When I manually start the activity, toast message works fine.

I cannot identify the source of the problem in the bug reports.

Thank you for your contributions

Here is how I set up the alarm:

```
private void setWakeUpAlarm() {

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 987654321, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
```

Manifest :

```
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:launchMode="singleTask"
android:taskAffinity=""
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
/>
```

MainActivity :

```
package com.via.vender;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SubscriptionInfo;
import android.telephony.SubscriptionManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Have to do the following in order to show without unlocking at wakeup
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Started with alarm!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: kindly attach logcat

Comment: @mad_lad, Sorry, I can't access the adb at this time. I am with online tools

Comment: `getApplicationContext()` change to `this`.

Comment: @blackapps Done but did not solve the problem

Comment: How do you know that the app launches at the proper time?

Comment: Also, why are you using `singleTask` launch mode and empty `taskAffinity`?

Comment: @DavidWasser, I tested it on real device and I saw it. For singleTask and taskAffinity see https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation#ExtendedNotification

Comment: The link you referred to is talking about using a special `Activity` being launched from a `Notification`. This is not the same case, and you don't have a "special" `Activity` here. You are trying to launch the normal root `Activity` of your application. Try to remove the special launch mode, task affinity and the "exclude from recents" flag and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: Also, `Toast` is not really a reliable debugging aid. You should add debug logging and check your logcat to see what is happening.